# MS Access, Formatted Subreport nested in Form

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access, report

I have a report of a message thread in MS Access. It is formatted in VBA using Detail_Format so that sent messages appear right aligned and received messages are left aligned when in print preview view.
All messages are stored in the same table.

I need this message thread to appear in a form where extra information can be added and viewed.
In this form the report shows without its formatting and without any clear way of formatting it.

I have tried using a subform but cannot format alignment etc for individual records.

Any suggestions?

Comment: My attempt at using a subform resulted in all messages aligning one side or another, conditional formatting seems limited to font, colour etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Report installed as subform/subreport on form can only display in ReportView. Format events only trigger in PrintPreview or direct to printer.

Have two textboxes side by side. Expression in each textbox displays data on condition of whether sent or received message.

=IIf([Type]="sent", [Message], Null)

=IIf([Type]="received", [Message], Null)

Use Conditional Formatting to set color and font.

No VBA needed and will work in either Report or Print views.

Comment: This method worked when the form was based upon a query with that concept - in the form itself the text boxes had an #error. The exact same expression worked fine in the query!

Comment: Did you mean `report` based on query? A field used in expression might first have to be referenced as ControlSource in another textbox. It's an oddity of report not form. But calculating in query perfectly reasonable.